# Replace all variables with true when they are bigger than 0.5 false when they are smaller than 0.5

Tags: r, machine-learning

```
FutureUsed     OppPartyCount  Agree  
1   0.3043478    0.28571429 0.4600666 
2   0.5251142    0.00000000 0.5109948 
3   0.5483871    0.00000000 0.4348406 
4   0.2790698    0.20000000 0.5039505 
5   0.3666667    0.00000000 0.4587339 
6   0.2142857    0.00000000 0.4371252
```

Lets say the dataframe name is `df` how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to evaluate boolean comparisons directly on `dataframes`:

```
df <- df > 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` option is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all( ~ . > 0.5)
```